# Which of these functionalities are available through the OpenText AppWorks REST API?

Tags: rest, api, opentext

I have no experience with OpenText.

I have a client who hosts a large amount of documents on OpenText Content Server. They would like to do things such as:

- Navigating through the file system and moving files between directories in the file system
- Upload files (PDF, MS Word docs, etc.) from local machines to the cloud file system
- Retrieve files from the cloud file system to be stored and opened on local machines, or read the content of files directly through the API
- Changing access rights (read/write) of users on Content Server

Are these options possible through the [AppWorks REST API](https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=%2Fawd%2Fresources%2Farticles%2F6102%2Fcontent%2Bserver%2Brest%2Bapi%2B%2Bquick%2Bstart%2Bguide)?

Lastly, is there any reporting analytics data available about the Content Server, e.g.:

- Number of uploads/downloads in a timeframe
- Number of users logged in a timeframe
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first 4 items are possible out of the box with the newer versions.
The latter two would need reports to be created on the server side which in turn then be called via rest.